# Large images as background in Android

Tags: android

I would like to create fragment with image as background. What I do is saving image in .png format, putting it to drawable folder and than using it as background in layout. First thing I noticed is that the view stutters, so I created different images for different densities. But I'm still afraid that in older devices with worser CPU view would statter.

Question

Do I have to use libraries like Picasso for adding images as background ? What is the best approach ?

Comment: if you take care for the requirements of the api, you mustn´t have fear. In fact, todays devices can do a lot of stuff. Read these two API articles: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html   http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: You can do another experiment by dropping the pictures in drawbale-nodpi folder.Please check if it is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think that base approach of using libraries like Picasso, Glide, UniversalImageLoader is for downloading images from network, caching, decoding, smooth loading in runtime. 
If you want just set background for imageView from your local resources the only thing you should consider is to do this efficiently. This is nice described by google [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and should be enough for your case.